# hooking up a four prong range plug

Tags: electrical

I have a range that I am hooking up, there is a red wire, black wire, copper wire and a white wire, I am asking if the white wire is a common wire or is it ground?

Comment: White is neutral, bare copper is ground

Comment: White is never ground. Green, green/yellow or bare is the global standard for ground, it is the only standard color worldwide.  Even Russia.

Answer (score 1):

### White is neutral, green is ground

White is the neutral (return).  Green is ground (safety).  Think of it this way: white is the normal way for power to return (like a drain pipe).  Green is the safety (floor drain) that deals with spills.